# jQuery - change opacity of element when scroll to it

Tags: jquery

I want each div `.project` to fade in when you reach it (and also make it fade in if you reload the page at the same position). I have the code below but it does not work quite as it should, sort of buggy when you scroll past the 2nd div.

```
var ticks = 0;
var scrolled = false;
$.each($(".project"), function(index, value) {
    ticks = ticks + 500;
    var elem = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
        var element_position = elem.offset().top;
            var screen_height = $(window).height();
            var activation_offset = 0.5;
            var activation_point = element_position - (screen_height * activation_offset);
            var max_scroll_height = $('body').height() - screen_height - 5;

            $(window).on('scroll', function() {
                scrolled = true;
                if(scrolled) {
                    var y_scroll_pos = window.pageYOffset;

                    var element_in_view = y_scroll_pos > activation_point;
                    var has_reached_bottom_of_page = max_scroll_height <= y_scroll_pos && !element_in_view;

                    if(element_in_view || has_reached_bottom_of_page) {
                        elem.animate({
                            opacity: 1
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
    }, ticks);
});

if(!scrolled && $(document).scrollTop() >= 1) {
      setTimeout(function() {
      $(".project").animate({
            opacity: 1
        });
      }, 250);
}
```

How can I accomplish my goal?

Comment: You'll want to include some HTML as well so others can replicate what you're seeing and attempt to offer possible solutions. Your question, as it is now, makes that difficult. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more details.

Comment: It is just the div mentioned in the post, nothing else